# Symfony date interval with multiple formats

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, view, dateinterval

I have a Date interval of an entity called worker with a period of time see the next functions:

```
// Get date of retirement
public function getRetireYear()
{
    $this->retireYear = $this->getBirthDay()->add(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));
    return $this->retireYear;
}

// Get time left for retirement
public function getTimeToRetirement()
{
    // Date of today
    $today = new \DateTime('today');

    // Calculate date diff between today and retirement day.
    $this->timeToRetirement = $today->diff($this->retireYear);

    // Return the time to retirement time formated
    return $this->formatTimeInterval(
        $this->timeToRetirement,
        '%r%Y years, %m months, %d days'
    );
}

//Format the dateInterval numbers as string
public function formatTimeInterval($aDateDif, $format)
{
    return $aDateDif->format($format);
}
```

The only value that is stored in the database here is `$this->getBirthDay()`, then `getRetireYear` generates the year of retirement of a worker (birthDay + 60 years).
`getTimeToRetirement` gives the time left to retire someone and `formatTimeInterval($,$)` is used to format the date Interval.

Now I need to be able to use this dateInterval in different formats, for instance sometimes I just need the year to compare as integer with other values in the views, so I need this year as a single value to be accessible on the views.

I have tried a few things but I do not know the correct way to do it, so I have not get the nicer conclusion to this issue.

Also sometimes I need the month and the day for other tasks, not only the year, this values should be accessible on the views because in the controller I just search for an ArrayColletion of objects and pass it to the view, otherwise I have to go up and dow the array collection.

For more information about the problem you can read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374066/symfony2-coloring-table-rows-depending-on-database-value-and-config-parameter/19376401#19376401)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off having the `getTimeToRetirement` method return the `DateInterval` and move the `formatTimeInterval` method out of the entity altogether as it is more relevant to `DateInterval` formatting than to your worker. You could then have your `DateInterval` formatted as you want when you need it.
Something along those lines.

In your worker entity class:

```
// Get date of retirement
public function getRetireYear()
{
    $this->retireYear = $this->getBirthDay()->add(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));
    return $this->retireYear;
}

// Get time left for retirement
public function getTimeToRetirement()
{
    // Date of today
    $today = new \DateTime('today');

    // Calculate date diff between today and retirement day.
    $this->timeToRetirement = $today->diff($this->retireYear);

    // Return the time to retirement time as a DateInterval
    return $this->timeToRetirement;
}
```

You can then use the `date` Twig filter to format the `DateInterval` in the view. See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html
If you need something more specific or encapsulated, you could also create a Twig extension for that. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Ok, I get your point, but how do i make this different formats available on the views? That is my main issue. If I call this on the Controller I have to go up and down the Array Collection and that is not very efficient I think, any way maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Of course it's better if you can format it in the view. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I have done, but may be is not the most practical way:

```
    public function getYearsLeft(){
    $aux = $this->birthDay->add(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));       
    //date today
    $today = new \DateTime('today');
    // Calculate date diff between today and retirement day.
    $this->yearsLeft = $today->diff($aux);                
    $aux2 = $this->formatTimeInterval($this->yearsLeft, '%r%Y');
    $this->birthDay->sub(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));
    return $aux2;
}
public function getMonthsLetf(){
    $aux = $this->birthDay->add(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));       
    //date today
    $today = new \DateTime('today');
    // Calculate date diff between today and retirement day.
    $this->monthsLetf = $today->diff($aux);        
    //$this->yearsLeft = $aDateDif; //('%r%Y');
    $aux2 = $this->formatTimeInterval($this->monthsLetf, '%m');
    $this->birthDay->sub(new \DateInterval('P60Y'));
    return $aux2;
}
```

I will convert this two functions in 3 functions simpler and more reusable, and maybe create the helper if I need it from outside this environment.In the Controller I access the config file:

```
         $redTime = $this->container->getParameter('time_red');
         $orangeTime = $this->container->getParameter('time_orange');
```

Of course no I have to pass the list of workers to the view and also the config vars. And now in the view I can just access the variables as follows:

```
                {% for aWorker in aWorkerList %}
            {% if aWorker.retireYear is defined %}
              {% if colorOrange > aWorker.yearsLeft %}
                  <tr bgcolor="orange">
                  {% if colorRed > aWorker.monthsLetf %}
                        <tr bgcolor="red">                                
                        {% elseif 0 > aWorker.yearsLeft %}
                                <tr bgcolor="red">                                    
                  {% endif %}                  

              {% endif %}
                        <td><a href="{{path('osd_retire_editworkerpage', { 'id': aWorker.idWorker })}}">Edit</a> 
                            <a href="{{path('osd_retire_deleteworkerpage', { 'id': aWorker.idWorker })}}">Delete</a></td> 
                        <td>{{aWorker.omang}}</td>                        
                        <td>{{aWorker.workerTitle}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.workerName}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.workerSurname}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.birthDay|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.dateOfEmployment|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.retireYear|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.timeToRetirement}}</td>
                        <td>{{aWorker.fileNumber}}</td>
                    </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

It works fine... with independence of the philosophy violations!?